# How do I sort an array alphabetically?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, alphabetical-sort

Having trouble with my syntax have tried a few things but still not getting it right. What am I not understanding?
Thanks

```
change = ['cents', 'pennies', 'coins', 'dimes', 'pence', 'quarters']
change.sort {|anythinghere| a <=> b puts "Ascending #{anythinghere}" }
```

Comment: Thank you!  how would I then get it to display in terminal?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Why not just `change.sort`? 
`Array#sort` without a block defaults to ascending sort, which is the block `{ |a, b| a <=> b }`:

```
sorted = change.sort # Ascending sort
sorted = change.sort { |a, b| a <=> b } # Same thing!
sorted
# => ["cents", "coins", "dimes", "pence", "pennies", "quarters"]
```

Note this block needs to account for the two variables you're comparing, unlike the block you wrote in your question. Including a custom comparator is only necessary if you wish to modify the way elements are sorted, e.g. if you want to sort in descending order: `{ |a, b| b <=> a }`

If you want to print a text representation of the array, use

```
puts sorted
```

and if you want to sort in place (not create a new arrray) use `sort!`

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway to display it?

Comment: If you're in a script and want to output a text representation of the array, use `puts` after you've saved the sorted array, i.e. `puts sorted`.

Answer (score 0):

coins = ['cents', 'pennies', 'coins', 'dimes', 'pence', 'quarters']

coins.sort!

p coins

Change your variable name from change to avoid ruby magic

Answer (score -3):

Use `sort_by` method:

```
change = ['cents', 'pennies', 'coins', 'dimes', 'pence', 'quarters']
change.sort_by { |change| change }
# => ["cents", "coins", "dimes", "pence", "pennies", "quarters"]
```

Comment: If you want to modify your current array use `sort_by!`

Comment: Why do you recommend `sort_by` (with a block) over `sort`? For one, it won't be as fast.